# Bind and validate Map property in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have an object with some simple properties that is bound to a form. The trouble is: this object also has a Map of objects which I want to bind to the same form.

The objects are "Event", "Donation" and "Donor", defined as follows:

```
// each event has a map of donations. the map key is the id of the donor
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Column
    private name;

    // the key for this collection is the id of the donor
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event")
    @MapKey(name="donor")
    private Map<Integer,Donation> donations;
}

// each donation is for one event, has properties 'amount' and 'donor'
@Entity
public class Donation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EVENT_ID")
    private Event event;

    @Column
    private Double amount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DONOR_ID")
    private Donor donor;
}

// the donors are set elsewhere in the application
@Entity
public class Donor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

The relevant code in my JSP is:

```
<form:form name="form" method="post" commandName="event">
    Name: <form:input path="name"/><br/>
    Donations:<br/>
    <c:forEach var="donation" items="${event.donations}">
        ${donation.value.donor.name}: <input name="donations[${donation.key}]" value="${donation.value.amount}" /><br/>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Finally, the form submits to the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEvent(@Valid @ModelAttribute Event event, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    // save event here
}
```

The form displays correctly, but when I save I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Integer for property null; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "myclasses.Donor@7cabee72"
```

From the error message I assume a property editor is needed. I've created property editors for simpler situations but here I'm stumped.

What's the right way to bind a collection of objects, when the collection is a property of your main object and each item of the collection has two properties (amount and donor)?

Comment: An idea, why not make Donor have an Amount property and then the collection will be a collection of donors who all have amounts?

Comment: @inkalimeva each donor can contribute to many events, once to each event